# How to configure writeConcernMajorityJournalDefault: true?

Tags: mongodb

I am new to Mongodb and I would like to configure the writeConcernMajorityJournalDefault in mongodb.

I tried to added to the mongo.conf and restart the service but failed.
I tried to use the command in Mongodb shell and run:

```
cfg = rs.conf()
cfg.writeConcernMajorityJournalDefault = true
rs.reconfig(cfg)
```

It still fail, do miss something of it?
Thanks

Comment: This question really belongs on [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com) which is the site to use for database administration and configuration questions. StackOverflow is for programming topics only, of which this question is not. **Please move your question to the correct site by deleting and reposting.**

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-write-concern/#modify-default-write-concern

Comment: I know the url already, i don't know how to configure in json.

Comment: My question is should I specify the write concern everytime in the coding? or the value is not use for this prupose>?